# Clean Domain Model With Entity Framework Concurrency Why Am I Forced To Use RowVersion?

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency, rowversion

Hi have a domain model which is nice and clean. Such as:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Body {gets;set;}
}
```

Why does Entity Framework force me to pollute the domain model with the RowVersion property to provide for concurrency?

My model doesn't want or need to know about this so why should I be forced to use it? Is there another way to perform concurrency checking? If so is it better/worse or faster/slower than adding a row version? Or can I add RowVersion somewhere else where it's not in the domain model. I'm using EF 4.1 with the fluent api.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a base class and put all properties for security, concurrency checking in there.

Comment: This will still pollute my domain model. Just in a different place.

Comment: But not too much, only a field in base class :-)